# Python CSV merge fields together

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

I have a `CSV` file with 100,000 rows in the end the rows will be inserted into `MS-SQL` database.
The issue is the field "auto_make" will have commas in the name.
How do I read the csv file that will accept those commas as part of the `"auto_make"`field?
example of `autodata.csv`

```
lot_date,sale_date,auto_make, vin<br>
2014-09-15 00:00:00,2014-09-15 15:12:13,Ford F250,be48a3a6-ba04-4df2-b07d-ab5b8b2f5351<br>
2014-09-15 00:00:00,2014-09-15 15:14:18,**Ford,Superduty**,0c1a7358-dd51-4db7-9632-993b050ac74c<br>
2014-09-15 00:00:00,2014-09-15 15:14:25,**Dodge,Charger,RT**,ac642530-6fcf-4f28-a075-62e12bbf7117<br>
```

The results fields should be as follows:

```
lot_date = 2014-09-15 00:00:00  sale_date = 2014-09-15 15:12:13 auto_make = Ford F250 vin = be48a3a6-ba04-4df2-b07d-ab5b8b2f5351<br>
lot_date = 2014-09-15 00:00:00  sale_date = 2014-09-15 15:14:18 auto_make = Ford,Superduty vin = 0c1a7358-dd51-4db7-9632-993b050ac74c<br>
lot_date = 2014-09-15 00:00:00  sale_date = 2014-09-15 15:14:25 auto_make = Dodge,Charger,RT vin = ac642530-6fcf-4f28-a075-62e12bbf7117<br>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you read each line in as a string the following will work:

```
line = "2014-09-15 00:00:00,2014-09-15 15:14:18,Ford,Superduty,0c1a7358-dd51-4db7-9632-993b050ac74c"

line_list = line.split(',')

lot_date = line_list[0]
sale_date = line_list[1]
auto_make = line_list[2:-1]
vin = line_list[-1]
```